# Imagine if the electron had a spin $s=3/2$. Would atoms in their ground state still display the Electron shell structure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, orbitals

My answer would be yes, since instead of starting with $2s+1=2$ electrons in the first shell you would have $2s+1=4$ electrons. This is a question my quantum mechanics prof posed in the last lecture, so I'm not sure if the answer really is that simple.

Answer (score 3):

The shell and sub-shell structure would be unchanged as that is governed by the $\ell$ and $m_\ell$ quantum numbers.

What would change is the maximum occupancy of each $m_\ell$ sub-shell, which would be $2s+1 = 4$.

Because of the increased repulsion among electrons now, the level structure of many-electrons will indeed change.

Answer (score 0):

In the ground state, all the "electrons" would be in the symmetric S state, so the antisymmetric spin wave function would be the antisymmetric combination of all permutations of spin-z projections with $S_Z=0$, where the permutations are from the symmetric group on 4 letters:
$$|S_{z,1},S_{z,2},S_{z,3},S_{z,4}\rangle=\frac 1 {\sqrt{24}}
\big[+|\frac {+3} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {-3} 2\rangle
-|\frac {+3} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {-1} 2\rangle
-|\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-3} 2\rangle
+|\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+1} 2\rangle
+|\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-1} 2\rangle
-|\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+1} 2\rangle
-|\frac {+1} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {-3} 2\rangle
+|\frac {+1} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {-1} 2\rangle
+|\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-3} 2\rangle
-|\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+3} 2\rangle
-|\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-1} 2\rangle
+|\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+3} 2\rangle
+|\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-3} 2\rangle
-|\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+1} 2\rangle
-|\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-3} 2\rangle
+|\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+3} 2\rangle
+|\frac {-1} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {+1} 2\rangle
-|\frac {-1} 2,\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {+3} 2\rangle
-|\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-1} 2\rangle
+|\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+1} 2\rangle
+|\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {-1} 2\rangle
-|\frac {-3} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+3} 2\rangle
-|\frac {-3} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+3} 2,\frac {+1} 2\rangle
+|\frac {-3} 2,\frac {-1} 2,\frac {+1} 2,\frac {+3} 2\rangle\big]$$

This factoring will continue in the 3 P-shell states and so on. The reason it is important is because, while the Pauli Exclusion Principle states that no 2 fermions can be in the same state (so counting $2s+1=4$ is sufficient), the more fundamental spin-statistics theorem states that indistinguishable fermions must be in an overall antisymmetric state, hence, constructing that state is important.

If you added a 5th spin 3/2 identical fermion to the wave function, there would be no way to construct a spin-wave function that is totally antisymmetric under the interchange of 2 particle labels.

Thus, a 5th fermion must change the spatial wave function by bringing in the lowest energy P state. While it is colloquial to say this fermion occupies the P state, what in fact happens is that occupation is shared among all 5 fermions in a manner that can be written as a space $\times$ spin wave function that is antisymmetric under the interchange of any two particle labels.